# Display report in new window on button click

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My report displays dates in a form where a radioButton is checked. When my radioButton is checked, the dates are displayed below, in a report. When I click the display button ("PRINT") these dates need to display in a new window.

```
private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
    }
}
```

My problem is here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Print dates", "Top partners");
    }
}
```

I tried to add the my report in `MessageBox.Show`, but receive an error

> Can not convert to string.

How can I easily generate the report in a new window? Or even export it to PDF or some other format?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to extract Date values from the Crystal Report and display them in a Message Box?

Comment: I used messageBox because don't know another method to display dates on a new windows. i need to extract dates from Crystal Report and display on a new windows, or save in a file (PDF, Excell)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to extract information from an executed Crystal Report to a program. It's not *impossible* (I suppose you could write a function that takes control of your mouse and copy-pastes the info) but it's definitely not recommended.

Instead, you'll want to write code in C# to do basically what the report does - Take the same dataset, perform any calculations or filtering of the data, and return the values in usable variables. Luckily this is all easily doable without the report, and you can directly copy the same SQL query the report uses and tweak that to run in C#. Return the values you need as a list, and boom - usable values ready for the taking.

But sadly there's no easy way to just grab a value from a report. Crystal's really old as far as technology goes, and a lot of the modern sensibilities don't apply.